# Persisting textbox value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtemplates

I'd like to save the newly entered values, so I could reuse them.  However, when I try to do the following, it does not work:

```
// el is a textbox on which .change() was triggered
$(el).attr("value", $(el).val());
```

When the line executes, no errors are generated, yet Firebug doesn't show that the value attribute of ***el*** has changed.  I tried the following as well, but no luck:

```
$(el).val($(el).val());
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is to preserve the values in the text boxes when I append new content to a container using jTemplates.  The old content is saved in a variable and then prepended to the container.  However, all the values that were entered into the text boxes get lost

```
var des_cntr = $("#pnlDesignations");
    old = des_cntr.html();
    des_cntr.setTemplate( $("#tplDesignations").html() );
    des_cntr.processTemplate({ 
                                Code: code, 
                                Value: val,
                                DivisionCode: div,
                                Amount: 0.00
                            });
    des_cntr.prepend(old);
```

This is the template:

```
<div id="pnlDesignations">
    <script type="text/html" id="tplDesignations">
        <div>
           <label>{$T.Value} $</label>
           <input type="text" value="{$T.Amount}" />
           <button>Remove</button>
           <input type="hidden" name="code" value="{$T.Code}" />
           <input type="hidden" name="div"  value="{$T.DivisionCode}" />
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Huh? You're trying to set an input field to its current value?

Comment: I modified the post to better explain what I'm trying to accomplish here.  Does that sort of clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

You want to save the previous value and use in the next `change` event?

This example uses `.data` to save the previous value. [See on jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/SgyP2/).

```
$("input").change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    var prev = $this.data("prev"); // first time is undefined

    alert("Prev: " + prev + "\nNow: " + $this.val());

    $this.data("prev", $this.val()); // save current value
});
```

[jQuery .data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want old/Initial text box value, you can use single line code as follows.

var current_amount_initial_value = $("#form_id").find("input[type='text']id*='current_amount']").prop("defaultValue");

If you want current value in the text box, you can use following code
$("#form_id").find("input[type='text']id*='current_amount']").val();